# NodeJS uploading Object to S3 using IAM Roles

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Folks,
  Trying to get NodeJS to upload an S3 Object.  I am trying to use IAM Roles instead of hard-coding creds.  I've created bucket policies from this [link](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxPOJBY6FE360K/IAM-policies-and-Bucket-Policies-and-ACLs-Oh-My-Controlling-Access-to-S3-Resourc)  The instance is launched via the role, so there should be no issues....

code:

```
function uploadToS3 (callback) {
            var newFile = '/dev/shm/uploads/'+req.query.mid;
            var s3 = new AWS.S3();
            var params = {
                ACL: 'public-read',
                Bucket: 'fooBucket',
                Key: req.query.mid
            }
            s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                    callback(err);
                } else {
                    callback();
                }
            })
        },
```

Anything I am potentially missing?

Answer (score 0):

User Error, Had an incorrect ARN in the S3 bucket policy.